# MATLAB Matrix factorization

Tags: matlab, matrix, factorization

I would like to know if there is a standard software package which is able to solve the equation `X=YZ` where `X,Y` are known matrices, `X` and `Y` are `nxm` matrices with `m>=n` and `Z` is a square matrix with `m` rows and `m` columns.

We end up with the matrix factorization `min ||YZ-X||_2`

Additionally I would like to impose restrictions on the solution `Z` but for the beginning I am more interested in existing packages.

Comment: start reading the documentation from [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) and then continue to whatever factorization method you like: [`chol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html), [`qr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html) and so on... Good luck.

Comment: Which is the unknown matrix you're solving for? z? and m>n so this is an underdetermined system?